how to check attributes and claims from Azure to ServiceNow
#System Arch
Front App: Power Automate
Resource App(Server): ServiceNow
External IdP of ServiceNow: Azure
#What I did
SSO between ServiceNow and Azure is already connected.
Attributes and claims that I want to send to ServiceNow are set on Azure.
#What I want to do
I want to verify that when custom connector of Power Automate tries to make connection, Azure sends attributes and claims to ServiceNow.
But, I cannot find attributes and claims to be sent from Azure to ServiceNow.
#What I tried to do
I looked up "Application log" and "Script log statements", but I cannot find any information related to attributes and claims.
I also looked up Azure log, but couldn't find any information related to attributes and claims.
